# Constructor not passing values (processing.org)

Tags: variables, parameters, constructor, processing

I have the class and main code listed below.

I can change values manually in the constructor but how can I extend the constructor so that values for all of the Tree variables are passed in as parameters?

I've done all the reading I can find re. constructors but am still very stuck. I'm using processing.org (java-esque) and am a n00b - please answer using small words :)

```
class Tree {

  // member variables
  int    m_lineLength;       // turtle line length
  int    m_x;                // initial x position
  int    m_y;                // initial y position
  float  m_branchAngle;      // turtle rotation at branch
  float  m_initOrientation;  // initial orientation
  String m_state;            // initial state
  float  m_scaleFactor;      // branch scale factor
  String m_F_rule;           // F-rule substitution
  String m_H_rule;           // H-rule substitution
  String m_f_rule;           // f-rule substitution
  int    m_numIterations;    // number of times to substitute

  // constructor
  // (d = line length, x & y = start position of drawing)
  Tree(int d, int x, int y) {
    m_lineLength = d;
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y; 
    m_branchAngle = (25.7/180.0)*PI;
    m_initOrientation = -HALF_PI;
    m_scaleFactor = 1;
    m_state = "F";
    m_F_rule = "F[+F]F[-F]F";
    m_H_rule = "";
    m_f_rule = "";
    m_numIterations = 5;

    // Perform L rounds of substitutions on the initial state
    for (int k=0; k < m_numIterations; k++) {
      m_state = substitute(m_state);
    }
  }

  void draw() {
    pushMatrix();
    pushStyle();

    stroke(0);
    translate(m_x, m_y);        // initial position
    rotate(m_initOrientation);  // initial rotation

    // now walk along the state string, executing the
    // corresponding turtle command for each character
    for (int i=0; i < m_state.length(); i++) {
      turtle(m_state.charAt(i));
    }

    popStyle();
    popMatrix();
  }

  // Turtle command definitions for each character in our alphabet
  void turtle(char c) {
    switch(c) {
    case 'F': // drop through to next case
    case 'H':
      line(0, 0, m_lineLength, 0);
      translate(m_lineLength, 0);
      break;
    case 'f':
      translate(m_lineLength, 0);
      break;
    case 's':
      scale(m_scaleFactor);
      break;
    case '-':
      rotate(m_branchAngle);
      break;
    case '+':
      rotate(-m_branchAngle);
      break;
    case '[':
      pushMatrix();
      break;
    case ']':
      popMatrix();
      break;
    default:
      println("Bad character: " + c);
      exit();
    }
  }

  // apply substitution rules to string s and return the resulting string
  String substitute(String s) {
    String newState = new String();
    for (int j=0; j < s.length(); j++) {
      switch (s.charAt(j)) {
      case 'F':
        newState += m_F_rule;
        break;
      case 'H':
        newState += m_F_rule;
        break;
      case 'f':
        newState += m_f_rule;
        break;
      default:
        newState += s.charAt(j);
      }
    }
    return newState;
  }

}
```

and

```
Tree tree;

void setup() {
  int SZ = 512;  // screen size

  int d = 2;
  int x = SZ/2;
  int y = SZ;

  size(SZ,SZ);
  background(255);
  noLoop();

  tree = new Tree(d, x, y);  
}

void draw() {
  tree.draw();
}
```

Many thanks,

@LuisLavieri - I studies your answer to my previous question but still stuck! I tried to start a chat with you (following your kind offer) but couldn't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just add them as parameters in the constructor. Here's an example:

```
Tree(int d, int x, int y, int one, String two, boolean three) {
```

And then when you call that constructor, you just have to provide the values for those parameters:

```
tree = new Tree(d, x, y, 1, "two", false);
```

Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html